# How percentage is augmented in gauge

Tags: bash, dialog, gauge

I have the following script, it works, but I don't know how it works,

What is the magic that gauge uses to use **whatever** as the variable that contains the percentage?

```
#!/bin/bash -x
cnt="`rpm -qa | wc -l`"
pct="`echo \"100/$cnt\" | bc -l`"
whatever=0
counter=0


for file in `rpm -qa`; do
    counter=$((counter+1))
    whatever=`echo $whatever+$pct | bc -l`
    echo $whatever | cut -d"." -f1
    sleep 0.1
    echo "XXX"
    echo Paquete $counter:
    echo  $file: $(rpm -V $file)
    echo "XXX"
done | dialog --backtitle "Verificando RPMs" --title "Progreso" --gauge "Procesando RPM's ..." 15 70 0
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no magic. The `for` loop explicitly writes `$whatever` (truncated at the decimal point) to `dialog`'s stdin, and `dialog` uses the stream of integers it reads from stdin to set the gauge position.

The `for` loop also changes the gauge's text, by outputting the new text in between `XXX` markers.

Quoting from `man dialog` (the section on `--gauge`):

> A gauge box displays a meter along the bottom of the box.  The meter indicates the percentage.   New  percentages  are  read  from standard  input,  one  integer  per  line.   The meter is updated to reflect each new percentage.  If the standard input reads the string "XXX", then the first line following is taken as an integer percentage, then subsequent lines up to another "XXX" are  used for a new prompt.  The gauge exits when EOF is reached on the standard input.

Comment: But how does dialog know that whatever is percentage ans not eg counter variable?

Comment: @sebelk: Because the entire line is an integer. As per the manpage, the line following the first `XXX` should be the percentage, but that line starts with a word (Paquete), so the gauge widget assumes that it's part of the text.  The remaining lines before the next `XXX` are definitely text, regardless of whether they are integers or not.